# Strange animation 'lag' after launch screen disappears and before viewDidAppear() method runs

Tags: swift, animation

After launch screen dismisses itself logo and title of my app (they are in container) should go closer to the top of the screen. Between dismissing launch screen and viewDidAppear method there is a strange 'blink' of my container in the background. As you can see I am using snapkit but it should have nothing to do with the problem. Here is my code:

```
class WelcomeScreenViewController: UIViewController {

var welcomeScreenView: WelcomeScreenView {
    return view as! WelcomeScreenView
}

override func loadView() {
    let contentView = WelcomeScreenView(frame: .zero)
    view = contentView

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.welcomeScreenView.checkWeatherButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 200)
    self.welcomeScreenView.checkWeatherButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showCityChoiceVC), for: .touchUpInside)
    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.welcomeScreenView.appNameLogoContainerVerticalConstraint?.isActive = false
    self.welcomeScreenView.appNameLogoContainer.snp.makeConstraints({ (make) in
        make.top.equalTo(self.welcomeScreenView).offset(100)
    })

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: [], animations: {
        self.welcomeScreenView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.welcomeScreenView.checkWeatherButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
    }, completion: nil)

}

@objc private func showCityChoiceVC() {
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(RegisterViewController(), animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Blinking comes from setting constraints in `viewDidAppear`. Use `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad` instead. `viewDidAppear` is invoked when your view actually appears on screen. So any changes that happen will be visible to the user.

Comment: It doesn't work the way I want but thanks for your reply. In launch screen my container is positioned in the middle of the screen, after app starts working it should animate to the higher position but with viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad methods the animation doesn't work (views just change their positions). I want user to see the container 'sliding' to the top of the screen but without the strange 'blinking effect'

Comment: You should place your constraints code in `viewDidLoad`, and keep the reference to  the constraint your want to animate. Then in `viewDidAppear`, you just do your animation by updating the constraint. In SnapKit `yourConstraint.updateOffset()`

Comment: @jakubradzikowski97 had any luck?

Comment: unfortunately not :/ I am still reading docs and stuff but can't find the solution. The problem with constraints in my project is that I have one constraint that is responsible of settling the view in the middle, then I deactivate it and set top anchor constraint for the same view. When I just updated the centerY constraint and gave it an offset it didn't help anyway.